# How to change programatically log level in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jmx, log4j2

I need to change programatically log level in log4j2 in my application. I know that there are several options for this:

1. Relying on core log4j classes
2. Using JConsole

Are there any solution to change log level without relying on core classes? JConsole is also isn't an option as I need to change it directly from my application.

Answer (score 0):

There are no methods in log4j-api to change the log level of a logger or an appender.

The cleanest way to do this is via JMX. Look at the source code for log4j-jmx to see how the log4j JMX client does this and then imitate this in your application.